# Xamarin.Forms Editor Control on iOS needs something to mark where numeric entry should be

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

On Android, when using an Editor control straight out of the box it is clear where the text/numeric data should be entered:

[image: Xamarin.Forms Android Editor Control]

On iOS it is not so obvious and I find myself having to guess where to press to bring the control in to focus:

[image: Xamarin.Forms iOS Editor Control]

The code shared across the controls:

```
<Editor Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="SomeTextHere"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Keyboard="Numeric"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    WidthRequest="68"
                    MinimumWidthRequest="68"
                    />
```

I'm not averse to writing a custom control if I have to, but is there an easier way?

Please note that I don't want to use placeholder text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **CustomRenderer** to implement it.

## Solution1

You can set the border of the Editor in iOS .

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using xxx.iOS;


[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor),typeof(MyEditorRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyEditorRenderer:EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                               
               Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
               Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;
               Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

## Solution2

If you do want to it display like in Android (only an under line)

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using xxx.iOS;


[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor),typeof(MyEditorRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyEditorRenderer:EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                               
               UIView lineView = new UIView() {

                    Frame = new CGRect(0,Element.HeightRequest-1,Element.WidthRequest, 1),
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,

                };

                Control.AddSubview(lineView);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

And you need to set the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` in Xaml .